# Google Chrome Extensions are not Syncing

Tags: google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions

I'm using chrome browser(latest version) on windows 7 in office and on Ubuntu 12.04 in home. I have just installed it in ubuntu. All the bookmarks have been synced. But none of the extensions has been synced in home's browser. I enabled the option 'Sync Everything'. But still the problem exists.

What should I do to sync the extensions too?

Comment: I am getting this in the latest Arch Linux and Chrome package. Just putting this here to say it is a present day issue for me, since this is from 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give it some time. As far as I remember when I first tried the sync feature, It took around 15 minutes and then the new extensions magically appeared.

Answer (score 9):

The issue is known: [Issue 170107](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170107)

The solution is to go to ***Extensions***, enable ***Developer mode*** and press ***Update extensions now***. That will immediately pull all the extensions for your account.

Answer (score 3):

First time is always slow because its getting all your bookmarks plus the extensions. Next few times will be super fast.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` just edit the file `hosts` type will be `file` and just remove the line `127.0.0.1 clients2.google.com` and run save the and run chrome again and inside `extensions` click on `update`.